# Stack columns and transpose

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data such as this:

[image]

I would like to separate each cell at the | and then transpose it like this:

[image]

Some sku's have hundreds of values, so it is not time effect to use "Text to Columns" and then transpose each sku manually.  Is there a way to do this via formulas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to this [article](https://www.excelcampus.com/install-power-query/) to find out how to use **Power Query** on your version of Excel. It is available in **Excel 2010 Professional Plus and later versions**. My demonstration is using **Excel 2016**.

Steps are:

1. Use **From Table** function under the `Data` tab to load your 2-column data table to the power query editor;
2. Highlight the second column, use **Split Columns** function under the `Transform` tab to split the column by custom delimiter `|`, and in the advanced option choose to put the results into **Rows**;
3. Close & Load the data to a new worksheet (by default).

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you so much!  That is awesome and did exactly what I need it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formula solution

Assume "Input table " put in A1:B2,

In "output" table A5, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$2,MATCH(1,INDEX(--(COUNTIF($A$4:A4,A$1:A$2)<LEN($B$1:$B$2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B$1:$B$2,"|",""))+1),0),0)),"")
```

In "output" table B5, formula copied down :

```
=IF(A5="","",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE("|"&VLOOKUP(A5,$A$1:$B$2,2,0),"|",REPT(" ",99)),COUNTIF(A$5:A5,A5)*99,99)))
```