# VB to Split rows keeping each row with the ID of column A in EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

My first post as I am trying to tackle an Excel issue.  If I can do this with a formula, I am open to that but all I have found thus far is VB solutions.

I am trying to take ID's in Column B and make separate rows out of them while they all stay matched to the column A text.  Example 1 is what I am given and I would like to see if I can get this to look like example 2.  I have 500 rows like this and need to create individual rows like example 2.

[image: Image of Example 1]

Example 1

```
Column A    Column B
1/15/2011   11HM1N1,21HM1N1,31HM1N1,41HM1N1,51HM1N1,D0HM1N1,F0HM1N1,G0HM1N1,H0HM1N1,J0HM1N1
```

This is what I am trying to achieve.

Example 2

```
Column A    Column B
1/15/2011  11HM1N1
1/15/2011  21HM1N1
1/15/2011  31HM1N1
1/15/2011  41HM1N1
1/15/2011  51HM1N1
1/15/2011  D0HM1N1
1/15/2011  F0HM1N1
1/15/2011  G0HM1N1
1/15/2011  H0HM1N1
1/15/2011  J0HM1N1
```

Here is the code I tried using that I found on SO.  It splits them out BUT instead of keeping the ID's that were originally tied to the dates, they were separated out and given some random number for the ID's after the first comma.  Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub test()
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim X
Dim Y
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim tempArr() As String
Dim strArr
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
objRegex.Pattern = "^\s+(.+?)$"
 'Define the range to be analysed
X = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp)).Value2
ReDim Y(1 To 2, 1 To 1000)
For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
     'Split each string by ","
    tempArr = Split(X(lngRow, 2), ",")
    For Each strArr In tempArr
        lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
         'Add another 1000 records to resorted array every 1000 records
        If lngCnt Mod 1000 = 0 Then ReDim Preserve Y(1 To 2, 1 To lngCnt + 1000)
        Y(1, lngCnt) = X(lngRow, 1)
        Y(2, lngCnt) = objRegex.Replace(strArr, "$1")
    Next
Next lngRow
 'Dump the re-ordered range to columns C:D
[c1].Resize(lngCnt, 2).Value2 = Application.Transpose(Y)
End Sub
```

Comment: what output does your code show after the very same input data as per your Example1?

Comment: VB =/= VBA, please edit

Comment: You can do this in **power query** easily. See my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58386198/stack-columns-and-transpose/58386242#58386242) the only difference is that in your case the delimiter is comma `,`.

Answer (score 0):

I would attempt this like so.  I have hard coded a date, but you can change to the value needed.   I can see you are using split and resize etc, but not sure on the need for RegEx?

```
Dim a() As String

a = Split("11HM1N1,21HM1N1,31HM1N1,41HM1N1,51HM1N1,D0HM1N1,F0HM1N1,G0HM1N1,H0HM1N1,J0HM1N1", ",")
b = DateSerial(2017, 3, 5)

Range("a1").Resize(UBound(a) + 1).Value = b
Range("b1").Resize(UBound(a) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(a)
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  The dates range from 1/1/2011 to 12/1/2018.  Is there a way to not hard code the dates to each row and allow for the dates currently assigned to those id's to be used?

Comment: Did you code the initial version and not know how to get a cell value?

Comment: Yes,  I was getting a random number.  I think I figured it out though when you provided "DateSerial".  Noob mistake.  I formatted that random number to date and boom!  I appreciate your help.

Comment: You were getting a number as I think you are using `.value2` instead of `.value`  You need to loop column A, get the value where I use dateserial, then do the split, and keep using `.end(xlUp)` or a running total to get the right destination row.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers provided were dateserials which I formatted the cell to a date format.

Comment: Please don't post this as an answer, add it as a comment.